# How can I find the bigrams per row?

Tags: python

I want to derive bigrams and used the following code to do so:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
def create_vectorizer():
    return CountVectorizer(lowercase=False, stop_words=['a', 'an','the','The'], ngram_range=(1, 3))

reviews_english["Review Gast"] = reviews_english["Review Gast"].astype(str).str.lower()

res = [(x, i.split()[j + 1]) for i in reviews_english["Review Gast"]
       for j, x in enumerate(i.split()) if j < len(i.split()) - 1]
res
```

I got the following results:
[image: Bigrams]

However, I would like to get the bigrams per row rather than for the whole list.
How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: What is a "row" and what is the "whole list"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CountVectorizer` to `fit_transform` per row. However since it requires a corpus/list of text you will have to convert your string in the row to a list of single string.

#### Sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ["a cat on the table", 
             "a dog under the table", 
             "an apple over the tree"]
})

cv = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 2))
bigrams = []
for txt in df["text"].astype(str).str.lower():
  cv.fit_transform([txt])
  bigrams.append(cv.get_feature_names())

df['bigrams'] = bigrams

print (df)
```

output:

```
                     text                                     bigrams
0      a cat on the table                 [cat on, on the, the table]
1   a dog under the table           [dog under, the table, under the]
2  an apple over the tree  [an apple, apple over, over the, the tree]
```